# Unable to import library in Remix IDE

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix

I am trying to import a library in Remix using:

```
import "github.com/Arachnid/solidity-stringutils/strings.sol";
```

However, I get a compilation error that says

> Unable to import "undefined": Not Found.

Any idea what wrong could I be doing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your link is broken. This is the correct link: `github.com/arachnid/solidity-stringutils/src/strings.sol`

You forgot **/src** part.

Comment: Hmm, I'll try myself and get back to you.

Comment: You are welcome @VishvaPatel . Also welcome to StackOverflow! Don't forget to mark my answer as accepted to signal that your problem is solved.